# Can I preprocess a Less css file?

Tags: php, css, drupal, less

I'm using [Less](http://lesscss.org/) with [Drupal](http://drupal.org), and I want to allow admin users to define colors for certain site elements globally. To clarify, we have a certain type of content, call it a "level" and admins can add a level to the site. Each level should have an associated color which will be the border color for certain divs, etc. I'd like the admins to be able to set the color through the cms and have that reflected in an external style sheet.

All the affected elements in the DOM are indexed by class. The only thing I can think of is in the main Less file to import a second Less or CSS file that would be generated dynamically by Drupal. I just want to make sure there's nothing I'm missing, for example a way to inline php in a less file and have the php executed before it's passed off to the browser or server-side less compiler.

Comment: Does it need to be Less? You can easily mix Less stylesheets with regular CSS.

Comment: Have you already tried the color module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this approach you're going to end up with hundreds (or whatever your audience is) of generated .less files. Not sure if it's the approach you wanna take.

Let users define colors and store that in db, then when user logs in, load his settings and generate CSS code which you simply embed in the header.php (or similar file that gets loaded on every page in Drupal):

```
<?php if ($user->logged_in) { ?>
<style type="text/css">
  .header {
    background-color: <?php echo $background-color; ?>;
    color:            <?php echo $header-color; ?>;
  }
  .content {
    ...
  }
  ...
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

.. and the rest of your styles is defined in LESS files.

Default user (not logged in) will get default colors for these elements, that you define in your LESS files. The above will simply overwrite them (so make sure you embed it **below** you call the main stylesheet).

I'd do that this way.

Comment: I should have been more clear: the changes made by users is for admins  and would be global changes to the site. Nothing on a user by user basis. Basically, we have some content type, call it "level" that we color code, and I want to allow users (admins) to set the color associated with each new level they add to the system.